# Button BackColor doesn't change

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, system

I want to change my button's color when it has a default color. I tried with code that in below but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

```
public void ClickedButton (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as Button).BackColor == System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control) {
        (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the control styles?

Comment: Why don't you just cast the `sender` to a local variable instead of doing two `as` casts?

Comment: define "doesn't work". Is this wpf? AFAIK `Button` has no `BackColor` property, maybe you are using a wrong namespace

Comment: @juharr The author might not know the difference between ``as``, ``is`` and casts

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman That's why I was pointing that out to them.

Comment: Button does have [BackColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158232(v=vs.80).aspx) Property.  -- [ButtonBase.BackColor Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.BackColor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: @BlackFrog not in wpf

Comment: Because the OP used **BackColor** in his question I made the assumption it's WinForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the **sender** to a **Button** first:

```
public void ClickedButton (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    if ((btn != null) && btn.BackColor == System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control)) {
        btn.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
    }
}
```

If this is a Windows Form control, that should work.

If this is a Web Form control, it may not (unless you are calling it as part of a postback).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add debug line to verify the current color of the button

```
public void ClickedButton (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add debug line here 
    string message = (sender as Button).BackColor.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(message);

    if ((sender as Button).BackColor == System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control) {
        (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
    }
}
```

That will help with your troubleshooting of code.  Also there is nothing wrong with your current code. Below is the result.

[image]

Here is result in the [Output Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx):

[image]